# Authy: Is it possible to gain access via backed-up filesystem?

Tags: authorization

If a user makes a complete backup of an android file system, is it possible to subsequently install authy on a different device, but authenticate as the original identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the contents of `/data/data/com.authy.authy` from one phone to the other seems to accomplish this.